# Read txt file including scientific numbers having D instead of E in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a txt file inculding 10 columns and and want to read it as a dataframe. The problem is that the numbers are outputs of Fortran and having a weird notation like 9.677975573367686D+00 and cannot be converted to float.

Thank you in advance.

The following codes did not worked.

```
data = np.loadtxt('data.txt', converters={0: lambda s: s.replace(b'D', b'E')})
```

```
float(val.replace('D', 'E'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code returned an error message it's best to post the whole message which can help others identify what was wrong.

My example tsv, the blanks are tabs, '\t'.

```
123.456D78  23.455D+00  456.789
987.65D3    45D-4   78.9D-03
9.677975573367686D+00   609.54d+4   123.456
```

This code worked to read the above tsv.

```
import numpy as np                                                                                               

def translate( s ): 
    s = s.replace( b'D', b'E' ) 
    s = s.replace( b'd', b'E' ) 
    return s 

conv = dict( zip( range( 3 ), [ translate ] * 3 ))
# Apply translate to all three columns.

print( conv )                                                                                                   
# {0: <function translate at 0x7fc3bf938430>, 1: <function translate at 0x7fc3bf938430>, 
#  2: <function translate at 0x7fc3bf938430>}

result = np.loadtxt( 'rtsv.tsv', delimiter = '\t', converters = conv )

result
# array([[1.23456000e+80, 2.34550000e+01, 4.56789000e+02],
#        [9.87650000e+05, 4.50000000e-03, 7.89000000e-02],
#        [9.67797557e+00, 6.09540000e+06, 1.23456000e+02]])
```